# Show update of total each month

Tags: mysql, reporting

Do you have an idea about how to resolve this?

This is an example of the DB I have: profile_table

```
user_id    status   points   created_at 
01          1        20       2011-01-01 01:03:35
02          1        50       2011-01-02 01:03:35
03          1        800      2011-01-04 01:03:35
04          1        152      2011-02-15 01:03:35
05          1        388      2011-02-20 01:03:35
06          0        40       2011-02-25 01:03:35
07          1        246      2011-02-26 01:03:35
08          1        335      2011-02-27 01:03:35
09          1        521      2011-03-08 01:03:35
10          1        5354     2011-03-14 01:03:35
11          0        22       2011-03-18 01:03:35
12          1        234      2011-04-03 01:03:35
13          1        222      2011-04-05 01:03:35
14          1        396      2011-04-24 01:03:35
```

Second Table: spend_points

```
price_id    spend_points   created_at
1           20             2011-01-01 01:03:35
2           10             2011-01-02 01:03:35
3           30             2011-01-05 01:03:35
8           40             2011-01-06 01:03:35
14          10             2011-02-03 01:03:35
7           50             2011-02-06 01:03:35
14          10             2011-02-07 01:03:35
2           10             2011-03-03 01:03:35
14          60             2011-03-12 01:03:35
14          10             2011-04-07 01:03:35
2           70             2011-04-12 01:03:35
14          80             2011-04-15 01:03:35
14          20             2011-04-21 01:03:35
```

The first table belongs to a group and this group can only spend points on items with 'price_id' = 14. In the spend_points table we have all items spend and there are some 14's.
The query I'm trying to build should show data from all users who can spend on price_id = 14. The table should have the total of points they have, total of spend points and all points they have had so far. Sounds easy when you only want that data but the problem to me is when I try to make a history of this. Every new month it should show an update of the previos month and also the previous month and so on.

Status = 0 means Inactive and

So the final table should look like this.

```
Detail                    January   February  March  April 
Total Active Users        3         7         9      12
Total Inactive Users      0         1         2      2
Total Point               807       2031      7928   8780      
Spend Points              0         20        80     190
Points So Far             807       2051      8008   8970
```

Do you guys have any idea how to do it? :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's long, but it will do it... based on a single year basis... if your data spans years, just add an applicable "year" where clause to each select/union.  The premise of the query is to pre-declare up front each month so we know where the "cut-off" date is for a given month aggregation (ie: Jan is sum of all less than Feb,  Feb is sum all up to Mar, etc).
Each one does require it's own pivot roll-up per month which is what makes this long, however, very simple to follow to get your results.  Not how I would plan to have such a query, especially on a large set -- where I would prefer to have a single table with "roll-up" values per month/year of the expected aggregations, and where applicable, have a trigger just update the counts, points, whatever as needed.

```
set @jan := date( "2011-01-01" );
set @feb := date( "2011-02-01" );
set @mar := date( "2011-03-01" );
set @apr := date( "2011-04-01" );
set @may := date( "2011-05-01" );
set @jun := date( "2011-06-01" );
set @jul := date( "2011-07-01" );
set @aug := date( "2011-08-01" );
set @sep := date( "2011-09-01" );
set @oct := date( "2011-10-01" );
set @nov := date( "2011-11-01" );
set @decem := date( "2011-12-01" );
set @nextYr := date( "2012-01-01" );


select 
      'Active Users' as Detail,
      sum( if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @feb, 1, 0 )) January,
      sum( if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @mar, 1, 0 )) February,
      sum( if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @apr, 1, 0 )) March,
      sum( if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @may, 1, 0 )) April,
      sum( if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @jun, 1, 0 )) May,
      sum( if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @jul, 1, 0 )) June,
      sum( if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @aug, 1, 0 )) July,
      sum( if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @sep, 1, 0 )) August,
      sum( if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @oct, 1, 0 )) September,
      sum( if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @nov, 1, 0 )) October,
      sum( if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @decem, 1, 0 )) November,
      sum( if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @nextYr, 1, 0 )) December
   from
      profile_table pt
union
select 
      'Inactive Users' as Detail,
      sum( if( pt.status = 0 and pt.created_at < @feb, 1, 0 )) January,
      sum( if( pt.status = 0 and pt.created_at < @mar, 1, 0 )) February,
      sum( if( pt.status = 0 and pt.created_at < @apr, 1, 0 )) March,
      sum( if( pt.status = 0 and pt.created_at < @may, 1, 0 )) April,
      sum( if( pt.status = 0 and pt.created_at < @jun, 1, 0 )) May,
      sum( if( pt.status = 0 and pt.created_at < @jul, 1, 0 )) June,
      sum( if( pt.status = 0 and pt.created_at < @aug, 1, 0 )) July,
      sum( if( pt.status = 0 and pt.created_at < @sep, 1, 0 )) August,
      sum( if( pt.status = 0 and pt.created_at < @oct, 1, 0 )) September,
      sum( if( pt.status = 0 and pt.created_at < @nov, 1, 0 )) October,
      sum( if( pt.status = 0 and pt.created_at < @decem, 1, 0 )) November,
      sum( if( pt.status = 0 and pt.created_at < @nextYr, 1, 0 )) December
   from
      profile_table pt
union
select 
      'Total Points' as Detail,
      sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @feb, 1, 0 )) January,
      sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @mar, 1, 0 )) February,
      sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @apr, 1, 0 )) March,
      sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @may, 1, 0 )) April,
      sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @jun, 1, 0 )) May,
      sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @jul, 1, 0 )) June,
      sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @aug, 1, 0 )) July,
      sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @sep, 1, 0 )) August,
      sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @oct, 1, 0 )) September,
      sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @nov, 1, 0 )) October,
      sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @decem, 1, 0 )) November,
      sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @nextYr, 1, 0 )) December
   from
      profile_table pt
union
select 
      'Spend Points' as Detail,
      sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @feb, 1, 0 )) January,
      sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @mar, 1, 0 )) February,
      sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @apr, 1, 0 )) March,
      sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @may, 1, 0 )) April,
      sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @jun, 1, 0 )) May,
      sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @jul, 1, 0 )) June,
      sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @aug, 1, 0 )) July,
      sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @sep, 1, 0 )) August,
      sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @oct, 1, 0 )) September,
      sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @nov, 1, 0 )) October,
      sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @decem, 1, 0 )) November,
      sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @nextYr, 1, 0 )) December
   from
      spend_points sp
union
select 
      'Points So Far' as Detail,
      PointsPerMonth.January + SpendPerMonth.January January,
      PointsPerMonth.February + SpendPerMonth.February February,
      PointsPerMonth.March + SpendPerMonth.March March,
      PointsPerMonth.April + SpendPerMonth.April April,
      PointsPerMonth.May + SpendPerMonth.May May,
      PointsPerMonth.June + SpendPerMonth.June June,
      PointsPerMonth.July + SpendPerMonth.July July,
      PointsPerMonth.August + SpendPerMonth.August August,
      PointsPerMonth.September + SpendPerMonth.September September,
      PointsPerMonth.October + SpendPerMonth.October October,
      PointsPerMonth.November + SpendPerMonth.November November,
      PointsPerMonth.December + SpendPerMonth.December December 
   from
      ( select 
              sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @feb, 1, 0 )) January,
              sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @mar, 1, 0 )) February,
              sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @apr, 1, 0 )) March,
              sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @may, 1, 0 )) April,
              sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @jun, 1, 0 )) May,
              sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @jul, 1, 0 )) June,
              sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @aug, 1, 0 )) July,
              sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @sep, 1, 0 )) August,
              sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @oct, 1, 0 )) September,
              sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @nov, 1, 0 )) October,
              sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @decem, 1, 0 )) November,
              sum( pt.points * if( pt.status = 1 and pt.created_at < @nextYr, 1, 0 )) December
           from
              profile_table pt ) PointsPerMonth,
      ( select
              sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @feb, 1, 0 )) January,
              sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @mar, 1, 0 )) February,
              sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @apr, 1, 0 )) March,
              sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @may, 1, 0 )) April,
              sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @jun, 1, 0 )) May,
              sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @jul, 1, 0 )) June,
              sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @aug, 1, 0 )) July,
              sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @sep, 1, 0 )) August,
              sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @oct, 1, 0 )) September,
              sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @nov, 1, 0 )) October,
              sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @decem, 1, 0 )) November,
              sum( sp.spend_points * if( sp.price_id = 14 and sp.created_at < @nextYr, 1, 0 )) December
           from
              spend_points sp ) SpendPerMonth
```

Answer (score -1):

In the spreadsheet world, people call what you want to make a "pivot table".  You're not going to get that out of MySQL without hand-building some massive ugly queries - it just doesn't fit in with what an RDBMS is meant to do.  You just have to get the per-month values & build out your report at the application level.  Similarly, those running totals are best just handled manually.